# How would I span two divs together in a 5 column div?

Tags: html, css

I have a 5 column div that I use throughout my site when I want to display five images or five groups of text on a line. On this particular div, I want to span box-5col-3 and box-5col-4 so the content in box-5col-3 goes across both divs.

I know I could easily create another div and change one of the divs from 20% to 40%, but what is the easiest way to do this?

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/4rj47uvn/

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<div class="container-5col">
    <div class="box-5col-1">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div class="box-5col-2">
        <img alt="Apple" height="173" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/apple/apple-06.jpg" width="173" /></div>
    <div class="box-5col-3">
                    <p><strong>Apples</strong><br />
                The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Gala</li>
                <li>
                    Honeycrisp</li>
                <li>
                    Pink Lady</li>
            </ul></div>
    <div class="box-5col-4">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div class="box-5col-5">
        &nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Here's my CSS:**

```
.container-5col {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

    .container-5col > div {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .box-5col-1 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .box-5col-2 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .box-5col-3 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .box-5col-4 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .box-5col-5 {
        width: 20%;
    }
```

Comment: I confess I have no idea what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Why can't you use the div `width: 40%`? Guess it'll not hurt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you are trying to do but since you are using flexbox.

I'm assuming that the 1st, 4th & 5th divs are to be zero-width and the other two divs expand to fill...except the 2nd which stays at 20%. Right?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.container-5col {
  display: flex;
}
.container-5col > div {
  text-align: center;
}
[class^="box-5col-"] {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.box-5col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
.box-5col-3 {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-5col">
  <div class="box-5col-1"></div>
  <div class="box-5col-2">
    <img alt="Apple" height="173" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/apple/apple-06.jpg" width="173" />
  </div>
  <div class="box-5col-3">
    <h3>Apples</h3>
      <p>The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Gala</li>
      <li>
        Honeycrisp</li>
      <li>
        Pink Lady</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box-5col-4"></div>
  <div class="box-5col-5"></div>
</div>
```

**Alternate Option**

The first 2 divs stay the same but the third div expands while 4 & 5 are zero-width.

[**Codepene Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gaampg)